# GL_PATCHES and index buffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

Are index/element buffer arrays ignored when drawing with GL_PATCHES and VAO?

using:

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, n, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

doesn't have any effect, is that ignored?
I can only draw **GL_PATCHES** as arrays, making it very wasteful in terms of memory.

Examples online suggest that you can use **GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER** with **GL_PATCHES** but as said they are ignored for me.

Using openGL4.5 on windows10 on a Radeon R9 295 X2 latest drivers.
Using openGL4.1 ob an iMac 27'' mid 2015.

Comment: All I see is you binding a buffer and uploading data to it. I don't see any part of your code where you render with that buffer. Or put it in a VAO. Or anything, really.

Comment: I only put the code that creates the index buffer, I didn't copy and paste the rest of the code because it's long and doesn't need to be there as I said the problem is only using the index buffers, not generally rendering a patch with VAO, which works as I've said.

Comment: What's wrong with your code has nothing to do with those lines in and of themselves. Those lines might succeed or fail, depending on what is around them. This is why we ask for [mcve]s. Indeed, the reason you haven't found the problem is because you've decided already that you know where it is.

Comment: Please stop patronising, I don't need that really. The question is easy: does data drawn with GL_PATCHES ignores index buffers? Can you answer that or not? The question is perfectly asked and does NOT need any minimal complete or verifiable examples, it just needs an answer to a simple question.

Comment: Moreover I've added the index buffer generation code just to show what I was talking about as depending on what GL version dialect or version you are using people know them with different terms. I repeat again, the code pasted is not the problem, it was to show what I was intending for index buffers.

Comment: "*The question is perfectly asked and does NOT need any minimal complete or verifiable examples*" The question only exists because your code is *broken*. As you stated in your question, you've seen examples of indices being used with patches. So you already have an answer to your question. You only doubt that answer because your code *isn't working*. So do you want your code to work, or do you want an answer to a question you already have an answer to?

Comment: No, the examples I've seen working were all rendering only 1 patch, IE 4 vertices, which would make the index buffer redundant as the first 4 vertices would have always been correctly rendered regardless of the index buffer being there or not. The question still stand, I don't know if my code is broken or if GL_PATCHES can use index buffers, if you know the answer, why don't just answer it instead of wasting our time?

Comment: Ok I've found the answer to my question, is: YES, index buffers are ignored.

And no Nicol Bolas you don't need to see any code to answer that question, you just need to know the answer.

Comment: Then whoever told you that was either lying or wrong. Go find a quote from the specification that says that.

Comment: If you are sure, why don't you answer it: "Index buffers AREN'T ignored."

Comment: Any chance you're using `glDrawArrays*` to render, as compared to `glDrawElements*`.  Using an element buffer requires using `glDrawElements` or similar functions, otherwise, it is ignored.

Comment: Hi Radical7, that's a very good guess, I'm using a combination of glDrawArrays and glDrawElements, as I said it's a complex code and not easy to extrapolate to a minimal flow, but you might be right, let me run some tests, please consider adding it as a real answer so I can tick it.

Comment: @Dado: "*please consider adding it as a real answer so I can tick it*" I thought your question was about whether a primitive type prevents indexed rendering, and specifically *not* about whether your code is broken. If that's the case, then his suggestion is not actually an answer to that question, so he shouldn't post it as an answer. And if it's not the case, then I was right to ask to see your code. So which is it? Also, if you want to let someone know that you've replied to their comment, you should use @ followed by their name.

Comment: Really why do you want to waste everyone's time here? I've told a MILLION times, the code is long and full of conditionals and it's impossible to have a small code extract because it WONT BE the same code that's running. His answer clearly implicitly say: the index buffers ARE NOT IGNORED if you use glDrawElements and they are if you use GlDrawArrays, which is EXACTLY what I was asking for. A simple Answer: YES/NO, and he also had an explanation for that. Something that your blah blah blah failed to do for 8 messages, your actions are deeply frustrating and time wasting for the community.